# neo4j query construction SyntaxException

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am writing a .NET airport application using neo4j for the first time. I have an API and can get my objects (Airports in this case) that are in the database.  I can also create new Airports with

```
public void Post([FromUri]string name, [FromUri]string code, [FromUri]string city, [FromUri]string state)
{
    string query = "(:Airport{name:'" + name + "',code:'" + code.ToUpper() + "',city:'" + city + "',state:'" + state.ToUpper() + "'})";
    var q = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher.Create(query);
    q.ExecuteWithoutResults();
}
```

That works fine. But I also want to make sure that the Airport does not already exist in the database. So I have tried to add in the code:

```
var existing = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher.Match("(a:Airport)")
            .Where((Airport a) => a.Code.Equals(code.ToUpper()))
            .Return(a => a.As<Airport>());
```

But when I run this code section it always throws a `SyntaxException`. I think that it is in the construction of the where clause.

My `Airport` class is

```
public class Airport
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The current resource I am using is https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher.

Two questions:

1. What am I missing here?
2. Are there other resources out there that would help me out?

Thank you

Comment: hi Michael - what's the Syntax exception you're getting?

Comment: Ahh no, I think I know what it is - I'll answer in a few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SyntaxException` is being thrown because `Neo4jClient` doesn't know how to deal with `.Equals` - if you take your query and look at the `existing.Query.DebugQueryText` you'll see it output (I'm passing in 'lax' as `code`):

```
MATCH (a:Airport)
WHERE a.Code"lax"
RETURN a
```

The `SyntaxException` comes from the `WHERE a.Code"lax"` - so you need to firstly change to using the `==` operator instead:

```
var existing = gc.Cypher.Match("(a:Airport)")
        .Where((Airport a) => a.Code == code.ToUpper())
        .Return(a => a.As<Airport>());
```

Now if we look at the `QueryDebugText` we get:

```
MATCH (a:Airport)
WHERE (a.Code = "lax")
RETURN a
```

But "lax" is lower case - we put `ToUpper()` there, so it should be "LAX" right??

A subtle nuance of `Neo4jClient` is that it needs to have the details as they need to be for the query, so doing:

```
code = code.ToUpper();
var existing = gc.Cypher.Match("(a:Airport)")
        .Where((Airport a) => a.Code == code)
        .Return(a => a.As<Airport>());
```

will generate:

```
MATCH (a:Airport)
WHERE (a.Code = "LAX")
RETURN a
```

You can use methods like `ToUpper` but you end up having to put them in a `string.Format` or interpolation:

```
var existing = gc.Cypher.Match("(a:Airport)")
        .Where($"(a.Code = \"{code.ToUpper()}\")")
        .Return(a => a.As<Airport>());
```

Which is a pain, as you need to remember the `\"` and open/close parentheses.

General tip is to always look at the `DebugQueryText` to see what is being generated.

Your second question as to more resources - I'm afraid there isn't :(

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly.  Also, thank you for pointing out the DebugQueryText.  I did not catch it before.  It will be very useful.